# Problemas al guardar un Decimal usando Entity Framework

Tags: c#

Cuando ingreso una cantidad de un producto, que es de tipo Decimal, mediante un TextBox utilizo:

```
decimal STOCK;
if(!decimal.TryParse(txtStock.Text, out STOCK))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Debe ingresar un valor correcto para el stock", "Advertencia");
    return;
}
```

Guardo la variable en `producto.stock = STOCK`, además valido desde el evento del TextBox que se ingrese un numero con coma.

```
 private void txtStock_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    //if (e.KeyChar == 8)
    //{
    //    e.Handled = false;
    //    return;
    //}


    //bool IsDec = false;
    //int nroDec = 0;

    //for (int i = 0; i < txtStock.Text.Length; i++)
    //{
    //    if (txtStock.Text[i] == ',')
    //        IsDec = true;

    //    if (IsDec && nroDec++ >= 2)
    //    {
    //        e.Handled = true;
    //        return;
    //    }


    //}

    //if (e.KeyChar >= 48 && e.KeyChar <= 57)
    //    e.Handled = false;
    //else if (e.KeyChar == 44)
    //    e.Handled = (IsDec) ? true : false;
    //else
    //    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Mi problema es cuando ingreso por ejemplo `0,5` me lo guarda como `1` o si ingreso `0,3` lo guarda como `0`.

Comment: ¿La columna `stock` de tu tabla `Producto` en la base de datos que tipo es? ¿Has verificado que la propiedad `stock` de tu objeto `Producto` almacena correctamente el valor del stock?

Comment: la columna stock de la tabla Producto es decimal. la propiedad almacena correctamente el valor del stock. pero cuando hago el savechanges() para insertarlo en la base de datos se graba solo la parte entera ej si es 10,4 se graba 10 y si es 10,5 se graba 11

Comment: ¿Por ningún lado se a sobrecargado el método `savechanges`? ¿Por algún lado no existirá `Math.Round` con tipo redondeo `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`? ¿Revisaste que el tipo de la columna en tu archivo `edmx` este bien?

Comment: el metodo savechanges no esta sobrecargado; no use el redondeo math.round ni lo otro. y en el edmx el tipo aparece como decimal [stock] decimal(18,0)  NOT NULL,

Comment: ¿Que base de datos usas?,  creo haber detectado el problema.

Comment: estoy usando sql express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En base a los comentarios, el problema que tienes es debido a la definición de tu tabla en tu base de datos.

Por ejemplo, cuando defines la columna `STOCK` como `DECIMAL(18,0)` se realizará el redondeo al momento de la inserción.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLA(
    STOCK DECIMAL(18,0)
)
INSERT INTO TABLA VALUES (15.5), (1), (0.5);
SELECT * FROM TABLA
```

Obtendrás:

> ```
> +-------+
> | STOCK |
> +-------+
> |    16 |
> |     1 |
> |     1 |
> +-------+
> ```

Para resolver tu problema, tienes que modificar tu columna y definir los dígitos decimales. Por ejemplo, `STOCK DECIMAL(18, 4)`. Donde, la cantidad de decimales será de `4` y la parte entero de `14` dígitos.

Si quieres modificar a través de una consulta, tendrías que hacer:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLA ALTER COLUMN STOCK DECIMAL(18, 4);
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [decimal y numeric (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql)

Comment: siiiii era eso. lo modifique si funciono perfecto. Muchas Gracias!!!!!!!!

Comment: No olvides de revisar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y dar por aceptada la respuesta. =)

Comment: como le doy x acertada a la respuesta?

Comment: En la respuesta hay un `check`. Podrías guiarte del ejemplo,  https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour con el texto _La persona que formula la pregunta puede marcar una respuesta como “aceptada”._